# How should I localize the interface of a PHP/MySQL website?

Tags: php, mysql, localization

Are there guidelines or state of the art ways to localize a PHP/MySQL website?

The idea here is to translate buttons, page titles and messages. The language of the website would be chosen at installation time and shouldn't change.

I have started creating text files containing lists of keywords with their translation, but it feels like reinventing the wheel.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the meantime, I found about an efficient way to build the array text file.

Wherever I want to translate a text item, I use the php [gettext()](http://php.net/manual/en/book.gettext.php) function aliased _() to encapsulate it.

Then, with [poedit](http://www.poedit.net/) I parse all my php files an create the translations automatically.

My generated .po (human readable) and .mo (compiled) localization files are put in:

```
locale/en_EN/LC_MESSAGES
```

I then initialize my translation application with this code:

```
$locale = 'en_EN';
putenv("LC_ALL=".$locale);
setlocale(LC_ALL, $locale);
bindtextdomain("messages", "locale");
textdomain("messages");
```

PROS:

- This way I do not have to keep track of my various text items and
  creating new translations can be done by non programmers.
- The output .po files also seem to be quite standard in their format.
- The .po files also reference every occurrence of the text to translate in my project.
- Another good thing is that if for some reason the .po translation files cannot be accessed, the basic text will be displayed by the gettext function.

Answer (score 2):

I did it once , I have added different file for different language.
Include that file , if no file included then include default (English) file.
And in that file define array ,

```
$array_language['welcome_msg'] = 'You are welcome';
```

So which file you'll include that array will show , related message else it will show default English file.

Comment: Thanks! This is basically what I was doing too. But I tried to study the code in wordpress (which is close to my project in terms of installing a localized version then leaving it in that language) and I found out that they did not do it this way. I didn't exactly get how they worked it out though.

Comment: You can do it by database but that's to complicated and maintenance is more. WordPress store everything in db.

Comment: You can try Transtable, a simple web interface for editing translations in php arrays. http://code.google.com/p/transtable